# Basis of linear space (simplices)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplex

Let $M=S^{1}\times S^{1}$ be torus. The projection $\pi : M\longrightarrow S^{1}$ induces $\pi_{*}: C_{k}(M)\longrightarrow C_{k-1}(S^{1})$.
if k=1 or k=2, how can we explicit the projection $\pi_{*}?$

Comment: If $C_k(M)$ is the simplicial chain group, then the set of $k$-simplices (with preferred orientations) forms a basis. I don't know what you mean by "in terms of matrices".

Comment: William, I just reformuled my question, I hope you can help.

Comment: I am confused about your indices, because normally a simplicial function induces a map between chain groups of the same degree, i.e. I would expect $\pi_*\colon C_k(M) \to C_k(S^1)$. What is the definition that you have in mind for $\pi_*$?

Comment: $\pi _{*}$ is a not necessary a simplicial. it decreases the dimension of the simplicial on $M$

Comment: In that case I don't know what $\pi_*$ is supposed to be, can you elaborate?